# FATE rsync error

Tags: ffmpeg, rsync

I am trying to rsync the fate-suite from the fate server to my local machine. When I run the following command:

```
make fate-rsync SAMPLES=fate-suite/
```

I get the following error:

```
rsync -vrltLW --timeout=60 --contimeout=60 rsync://fate-suite.ffmpeg.org/fate-suite/ fate-suite/
receiving incremental file list
created directory fate-suite
rsync: read error: Connection reset by peer (104)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at io.c(802) [receiver=3.1.0]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (15128 bytes received so far) [generator]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [generator=3.1.0]
make: *** [fate-rsync] Error 12
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: It seems like either a firewall settings issue on your local machine or a heavy-load issue on ffmpeg fate server. If you repeatedly experience this problem, then I guess it'a the firewall thing, coz I just tried it, and it works out fine.

Comment: Yeah, something was wrong with the network. I asked on the IRC and they told me a workaround this.